# InvalidStateError, objects state must be opened

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xml

This JavaScript code is supposed to read an xml document and output it into a table. If the user selects bid, a prompt will ask for a new value and the Start Price will be changed immediately. However, this isn't the case for my code. When I have clicked the Bid button to update the value, it receives a new price and appends it to the xml. However, Start Price on the page does not change. I have found out that this error happens when I submit the button in the first javascript function. The error is an Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

This is the JavaScript

```
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

function loadXMLDoc(url)
{
    var table
    var item
    var items
    var i;
    var sendoff;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) &&(xmlhttp.status == 200))
        {
            table="<table>";
            var serverResponse = xmlhttp.responseXML;
            item=serverResponse.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Product");

            for (i=0;i<item.length;i++)
            {
                table=table + "<tr>";
                items=item[i].getElementsByTagName("ItemName");
                {
                    table=table + "<td>Item Name : </td>"+"<td>" +   items[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
                    iname =  items[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                    //document.getElementById('test').innerHTML=sendoff;
                }
                table=table + "</tr>";
                table=table + "<tr>";

                items=item[i].getElementsByTagName("Category");
                {
                    table=table + "<td>Category : </td>"+"<td>" + items[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
                }

                table=table + "</tr>";
                table=table + "<tr>";
                items=item[i].getElementsByTagName("Description");
                {
                    table=table + "<td>Description : </td>"+"<td>" +     items[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
                }

                table=table + "</tr>";
                table=table + "<tr>";
                items=item[i].getElementsByTagName("StartPrice");
                {
                    table=table + "<td>Start Price : </td>"+"<td>" +     items[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
                }

                table=table + "</tr>";
                table=table + "<tr>";
                items=item[i].getElementsByTagName("Owner");
                {
                    table=table + "<td>Owner  : </td>"+"<td>" + items[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
                    iowner =  items[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                    //document.getElementById('test').innerHTML="AA"+iowner;
                }

                table=table + "</tr>";
                table=table + "<tr>";
                table=table + "<td><input type=\"submit\" onclick=\"itembid('"+ iname + "','"+ iowner +"')\" value=\"Bid\"></td>";
                table=table + "<td><input type=\"submit\" onclick=\"\" value=\"Buy It Now\"></td>";
                table=table + "</tr>";
            }
            table=table + "</table>";
            document.getElementById('listinglist').innerHTML=table;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function itembid(iname,iowner)
{
    var newbid = prompt("Please enter your bidding price");
    var itemname = iname;
    var ownername = iowner;
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "readxml.php?newbid=" + encodeURIComponent(newbid) +  "&itemname=" + encodeURIComponent(itemname) + "&ownername=" +   encodeURIComponent(ownername) +"&date="+ Number(new Date), true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = loadXMLDoc;
}
```

This is the php page that the second function calls

```
<?php
require_once("sessioncheck.php");
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
?>

<?php

$newbid = $_GET["newbid"];
$itemname = $_GET["itemname"];
$ownername = $_GET["ownername"];
if (!empty($_SESSION['fname']))
{
    toXml($newbid,$itemname,$ownername);
}

function toXml($newbid,$itemname,$ownername)
{
    //compare passed owner name to internal xml owner name
    //echo "BB".$newbid.$itemname.$ownername;

    $xml = simplexml_load_file("auction.xml");
    $sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->asXML());
    foreach($sxe->children() as $items)
    {
        if($items->ItemName == $itemname)
        {
            //echo "Current Price".$items->StartPrice;
            $items->StartPrice = $newbid;
            //echo "New Price".$items->StartPrice;
        }
    }

    $sxe->asXML("auction.xml");
    return $sxe;
    //print_r($xml);
}
```

Could this be linked to the onload function in the body of my html file?

`<body onload="loadXMLDoc('auction.xml')"`

Comment: multiple requests using variable `url` that doesn't seem to be defined. Duplicate `onreadystatechange` assignments ...very hard to figure out how many requests you are trying to make here. I got the impression it was one...but i see 3

Comment: the variable url is the "auction.xml" that was passed from the html. Should I remove the onreadystatechange from the first function? I have tried that before but it stopped the table from appearing.

Comment: Should I read the xml file via normal javascript and then only use onreadystatechange in the second function?